# Cannot determine key of property in object Nodejs

Tags: node.js, object, error-handling

I'm trying to handle some error and modify error message but when i `console.log(error)`, it give a object like this:

```
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'G:\Fwork\fwork-nodejs-back\src\controllers\base\ava.txt']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path:
   '......//ava.txt' }
```

I tried `Object.keys(obj)`, it gave an array
without array in object `[ 'errno', 'code', 'syscall', 'path' ]`

So anyone can help?

Comment: What obj contains and what is the output r u getting? Is it [ 'errno', 'code', 'syscall', 'path' ]?

Comment: @ajaykumarmp I want to get array ```[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'G:\Fwork\fwork-nodejs-back\src\controllers\base\ava.txt']``` but it doesn't have any key to call.

Comment: @simpsons3 - You just call `obj.toString()` and that will get you that value.  That's what my answer explains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first item is the result of `.toString()` on an Error object and is just something that `console.log()` decides to show for that particular type of object, not something actually a property of the object.  You will notice it's a conglomeration of the other property values.

The result of `Object.keys()` are the actual enumerable own property names on the Error object.

You can see it yourself with this test code:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile("whateverFileThatDoesNotExist", (err, result) => {
    console.log(err);    
    console.log(err.toString());
});
```

The `err.toString()` value for the above code is this:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\code\test\temp\whateverFileThatDoesNotExist'
```

If you want to retrieve that value yourself, you can call `obj.toString()` yourself.

Comment: I have tried ```.toString()``` and it display same as you. However, I want to modify this error message like: ```Error: error here``` but do not change type from object to string.

Comment: @simpsons3 - I don't understand.  Please edit your question to show the EXACT result you are trying to achieve.  `console.log()` does what it does.  That's built-in.

Comment: sorry for slow reply. I want to modify the message error like this :
`{ [Error: ENOENT: this message here, open 'G:\Fwork\fwork-nodejs-back\src\controllers\base\ava.txt']` . 
The message object contain properties ```code```, ```syscall```, ```path``` which create a form like:
 `[code]: 'no such file or directory', [syscall] [path]`
So i want to modify only message without using string method. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, i got my answer by using `let error = new Error(err.code + ': daasda, ' + err.syscall + ' '+ err.path);` Thanks for help.
And one more question, how to create a object with array like that?

Comment: @simpsons3 - Apparently you don't understand that the object does NOT have that property. It's not stored in the object and it's not an array. It's console.log() that just decides to display that when it encounters an Error object. It's in the console.log() display logic as a combination of those other properties.  The combined value is not stored in the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to modify the error message, maybe considering create your own [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) object

```
try {
    /* ... */
} catch (err) {
    // handle error here

    // create your own error message
    throw new Error('My custom error message');
}
```

Comment: I tried ```new Error``` but i want this message look like this: { [Error: ENOENT: this message here, open `'G:\Fwork\fwork-nodejs-back\src\controllers\base\ava.txt']` without using string method.

Answer (score 0):

**the following code will work**

```
fs.readFile("whateverFileThatDoesNotExist", (err, result) => {
  Object.keys(err).forEach(val=>console.log(err[val]))
});
```

**output**
-2
ENOENT
open
whateverFileThatDoesNotExist

OR

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile("whateverFileThatDoesNotExist", (err, result) => {
    console.log(err.message);
    console.log(err.errno);
    console.log(err.code);
    console.log(err.stack);
    console.log(err.syscall);
    console.log(err.name);
    console.log(err.path);
});

this is the output from above console logs


ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'whateverFileThatDoesNotExist'
-2
ENOENT
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'whateverFileThatDoesNotExist'
open
Error
whateverFileThatDoesNotExist
```

Comment: is it possible to print only ```no such file or directory```?